# Google Scripts automerging with specific format

Tags: google-apps-script, merge, scripting, google-sheets

I have a Google form that asks the user 3 questions,in spreadsheets i am receiving each answer in different column.
Example: [image: Example]

Is there any script that spreadsheets will automatically take the values of columns C,D,E and combines them in this specific format into column C "( $answerC _ $answerD _ $answerE )" ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
//you need to set an installable onFormSubmit trigger.
//Go to Resources, current projects triggers and set
// a trigger for combine, from spreadsheet, onFormSubmit.
function combine(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getSheets()[0]//get the frist sheet ('Form Responses 1')
  var lr=s.getLastRow() //get last row
  var c=s.getRange(lr, 3, 1, 3).getValues()//get values of columns C, D, and E
  var array=[]
  array.push(c[0][0]+" "+c[0][1]+" "+c[0][2]) //create array of values. If you want "_" separater replace space with "_".
  s.getRange(lr, 3, 1, 3).clearContent() //clear submitted values
  s.getRange(lr, 3, 1, 1).setValue(array) //set combined values in column C
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for! Thanks :D